# Drop down value to Textbox (Not HTML Event Handlers)

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm working with static HTML that is written in stone. I cannot add an onclick to the dropdown menu, which is usually what I would do.

The following is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replicate() {
    var tb1 = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownList_Country_17");
    var tb2 = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox_State_19");
tb2.value = tb1.value;
}
</script>
```

Of course, this works fine for the actual "transfer" of data from the drop down to textbox, but it never gets executed. Usually I would execute the function "onclick" in the HTML, but I cannot do that. Is there another way to "listen" for a click on that dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Just register the handler:

```
document.getElementById("yourdropdownID").onchange = replicate;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use JQuery?  Link to JQuery (like all javascrip files) and do the following in a script tag somewhere (or add to your current script tag.

```
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        //Use the ID of the control here:
        $("#ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownList_Country_17").change(function(){
         replicate();
        });


     });
     <script>
```